# Flip-flop behavior change size

Tags: circuitikz

[image]

How do you change the height and width of flip-flops?
Here is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw (1,0) node[not port] (not1) {} (3,0) node[not port] (not2) {} (0,0) -- (not1.in) (not2.in) -- (not1.out) ++(0,-1) node[ground] {} to[C] (not1.out) (not2.out) -| (4,1) -| (0,0) ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the sizes of the circuit you posted (which can be found in the `tikzcircuit` documentation), my suggestion is to adopt the `scale` option provided by `tikzcircuit` for the family of components you are interested in.

This, however, causes the need to change the coordinates which are used to place the components.
Therefore, my suggestion is to switch from an absolute to a relative placement using the `positioning` `tikz` library.
The `calc` library is used to calculate relative position of other intermediate nodes used to connect the in and out ports.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
Original circuit
\begin{center}
    \begin{circuitikz}[]
        \draw (1,0) node[not port] (not1) {} (3,0) node[not port] (not2) {} (0,0) -- (not1.in) (not2.in) -- (not1.out) ++(0,-1) node[ground] {} to[C] (not1.out) (not2.out) -| (4,1) -| (0,0) ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

Enlarged (scaled) circuit

\begin{center}
    \ctikzset{logic ports/scale=2}
    \begin{circuitikz}[
            node distance = 2cm,
        ]
        % first place the nodes
        \node [not port] (not1) {};
        \node [not port] (not2) [right=of not1] {};
        \node [ground] (gnd) [below=of not1.out] {};
        % then draw the connections
        \draw (not1.out) to[C] (gnd);
        \draw (not1.out) -- (not2.in);
        \draw (not2.out) -| ($(not2.out)+(0.5,2)$) -- ($(not1.in)+(-0.5,2)$) |- (not1.in);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: You are welcome! remember also to [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up)/[accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) the answers that helped you the most ;)
It is preferred to a "thank you" comment (this also applies to the other question you posted, for which you already have multiple answers)